# UICollectionView Force Load All Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview

My requirement is very simple. I just want to load all the data defined in my datasource.
In my datasource I have defined 16 rows. I saw, my `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is not calling more than 7 times. After scrolling down it calls again the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and loads rest of the item. Guys, can anyone please suggest me how to load all the data at once.

This would be really appreciate.

Comment: That is how it is supposed to work. It only creates cells for what is on screen. Those cells are then reused. This is correct. Creating all cells can potentially cause a memory warning. What is it that makes you want to load them all? Why is it that what it is currently doing is not correct?

Comment: It is the reuse of the cells. Read the documentation

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What about the default behavior is causing issues for you?

Comment: You can use static cells if you want everything to be loaded once otherwise don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks a lot. I discovered the problem and have my solution. My CollectionView frame had changed during some UI operations. Thats why I would see empty white space inside CollectionView and suddenly a row arrives there. I just adjusted the CollectionView display frame at runtime and it automatically fixs. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot. I discovered the problem and have my solution. My CollectionView frame had changed during some UI operations. Thats why I would see empty white space inside CollectionView and suddenly a row arrives there. I just adjusted the CollectionView display frame at runtime and it automatically fixs. Thanks